# Div is showing for 1 second after I want it hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have two div's in the same place and I only show one at a time. I have a function that hides one div and then shows the other and vice versa. My problem is that one of the divs is showing in the corner of the container after I hide it for 1 second, it is originally centered but when I hide it I set the width and height to 0. When it is in the corner the styling is gone and I only see the text from it and the button I use that holds the function to change divs, and it disappears after a second. I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate some help with this.

here is an example html of this -

```
<div class='event-container'>
                <div class='events hidden'>
                    <span class='no-Events event-message'>no Events this Day</span>
                    <span class='event-title event-message'></span>
                    <span class='event-desc event-message'></span>
                    <button class='show-event-form rotate'>Submit</button>
                </div>
                <form class='new-event-form'>
                    <legend>Submit New Event</legend>
                    <input id='new-event-title' type='text' name='title' placeholder='title'>
                    <input id='new-event-desc' type='text' name='desc' placeholder='desc'>
                    <input type='submit' class='submit-event rotate' value='submit'>
                </form>
  </div>
```

Either the .events div will show or the .new-event-form Form will show/hide.

I use these css classes to show/hide them

```
.hidden {
    height: 0; opacity: 0; width: 0;
    transition: height 0ms 400ms, opacity 200ms 0ms, width 0ms 0ms;
}

.visible {
    height: 100%; opacity: 1; width: 100%;
    transition: height 200ms 0ms, opacity 600ms 200ms, width 0ms 0ms;
}
```

here is the css for .new-event-form and .events

```
.new-event-form{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align: center;
}

.events{
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; /*center children vertically*/
}
```

And this  function changes the div's between show/hide classes

```
const hideShowEventsDiv = ()=> {
     let eventsDiv = document.querySelector('.events');
     let newEventForm = document.querySelector('.new-event-form');

     if(eventsDiv.classList.contains('hidden')){
         //show Events
        newEventForm.classList.add('hidden');
        newEventForm.classList.remove('visible');
        eventsDiv.classList.remove('hidden');
        eventsDiv.classList.add('visible');
     } else {
         //show new Event Form
        eventsDiv.classList.remove('visible');
        eventsDiv.classList.add('hidden');
        newEventForm.classList.remove('hidden');
        newEventForm.classList.add('visible');
     }   
 }
```

eventListner for this

//Submit form and show event or new event form

```
 document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
     if(e.target.classList.contains('rotate')){
        e.preventDefault();
        newEvent.submit();
        newEvent.clear();
     //  ---> this one hides/shows the div 
       hideShowEventsDiv();
     }
 });
```

This problem is only happening for the .events Div. The .new-event-form Form is not having any issues with fading or showing in the corner and then dissapearing when I try to hide it, that is only the .events div with this problem

Comment: I'm sorry if I missed it. But, what triggers this show/hide event?

Comment: @C.RaysOfTheSun I think the css transitions kick in after the class changes to `hidden` or  `visible`

Comment: @I.R.R. Yeah. But, like, what triggers the class change? A button? Does it happen onload? :)

Comment: @C.RaysOfTheSun right, my bad. Us computer folk are like computers too sometimes -- error: context not defined.

Comment: Hahaha! All's good lol

Comment: Sorry I didn't put it in there. It's an eventListener that activates when the document is clicked and select the correct target with the rotate class name which has the hideShowEventsDiv() function. I didn't add it because I'm sure thats not the problem. Should I add it?

Comment: @kokokonoi, well more information is better (for me at least). But, I just wanted to know so I can try and simulate the problem :)

Comment: @kokokonoi gotcha. See if my answer solves the issue :)

Comment: @kokokonoi, I updated the answer to mimic your layout :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about how the date text ("No events on [date]") and the button get all squeezed up during the transition, it's because you shrink their parent by setting its `width` property to 0. setting the `overflow` property to `hidden` in your *hidden class* will solve this issue :)

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  let btn = document.querySelector('#toggler');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // grab the events div
    let eventsDiv = document.querySelector('#events');
    // grab our mock form
    let eventForm = document.querySelector('#event-form');
    // toggle does the conditional you had before
    // it ascts like a switch, removing the class if its there
    // and adding it in otherwise.
    eventForm.classList.toggle('hidden');
    eventsDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
};
```

```css
.big-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 15px;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-item {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px black;
}

.hidden {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#events {
  background-color: green;
}

#event-form {
  background-color: red;
}

#placeholder {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
  <div class="big-container" id="placeholder">
    <input type="button" value="toggle visibility" id="toggler">
  </div>
  <div class="big-container">
    <div class="container" id="events">
      <span class="container-item">There are no events on November 17, 2018</span>
      <span class="container-item"></span>
      <span class="container-item"></span>
      <button class="container-item" id="btn-events">I am a button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container hidden" id="event-form">
      <div class="container-item"></div>
      <div class="container-item"></div>
      <div class="container-item"></div>
      <button class="container-item" id="btn-submit">I am another button</button>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/pQrEXL) and a [modified version of your pen](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/WYERGB) :)

Comment: Thank you for the help I appreciate it.